# how do I make a buttonGUI that when clicked shows a GUI?

Tags: lua, roblox

I would like this to be a buttonGUI or a proximity prompt (proximity prompt preferred)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't given much context of the file structure, so I can only do my best to help.

So first you need to add a event listener to the button. So as a child of the button add a `localscript` and in that script add the listener.

```lua
local GUI_Holder = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
local UI = GUI_Holder.Your_UI_To_Activate -- Path to the GUI element

script.Parent.MouseButton1Click:Connect(function()
   UI.Enabled = true
end)
```

Lines one and two look pretty bad however you can replace then with you own way of fetching the UI. (https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/class/TextButton)

If you need any more help reply to this :)

-- Harvey

Answer (score 0):

Harvey has a good answer but I recommend using button.Activated

```lua
local GUI_Holder = game:GetService("Players").LocalPlayer:WaitForChild("PlayerGui")
local UI = GUI_Holder.Your_UI_To_Activate -- Path to the GUI element

script.Parent.Activated:Connect(function()
   UI.Enabled = true
end)
```